# Can't console log in short hand arrow function when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

When debugging an arrow function in javascript you can write like this:

```
const sum = (a, b) => console.log(a, b) || a + b;
```

This will first console log `a` and `b` and then return the actual result of the function.
But when using Typescript it will complain about console log not being able to be tested for truthiness:

> An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness

This feels like a valid complaint, but at the same time it's a neat trick to debug arrow functions and I would very much like to not have to add curly braces everywhere I have arrow functions if possible.

Even though the log is only there temporarily, are there any way to get Typescript to accept this pattern without using `@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to use comma operator:

```
const logger = (a, b) => (console.log(a, b), a + b);
```

Comment: +1 This is by far the optimal solution, as it's not a workaround but a well documented feature. The only issue is, it would be a bit harder to refactor once the OP wants to remove all the `console.log` expressions.

Comment: Thanks! This looks nice, but could you please explain the mechanics of this? What is actually being returned? I'm fairly used to JS but I've never seen what looks like a tuple in JS :)

Comment: @mottosson "[The comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand".

Answer (score 4):

Casting the `console.log` expression to a boolean should work around this.

For example:

```
const sum = (a, b) => Boolean(console.log(a, b)) || a + b;
```

Since the expression returns `undefined`, casting it to boolean would always be `false`, ensuring any following expression will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the `console` type beforehand. Do it once, and you won't have to modify any of your other calls to `console.log`:

```
declare const console = {
    log: (...args: unknown[]) => undefined,
    // etc
};

const sum = (a: number, b: number) => console.log(a, b) || 'foo';
const another = (a: number, b: number) => console.log(a, b) || 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use as below:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b && console.log(a, b);
```

this is my suggestion. :D

Comment: Only issue with this code is that it wont log if `a + b` add up to `0`. (`sum(0, 0)`, `sum(-1, 1)`, etc.)